# How to use table loader in ztree?

Tags: experimental-design, ztree

I am programming a so-called "Alien Game" based on Billinger, Stieglitz and Schumacher in ztree. However, I am struggling to my NK matrix into ztree.

Does anyone have experience with the "table loader" function in ztree and can help me understand how I need to transform my excel/txt sheet and/or what the command is?

Thanks in advance already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table loader essentially loads a text file. Things to remember:

- **First column corresponds to the table** name you'd like to import to
- **First row corresponds to the variable name**
- **Values are tab separated**
- **String variables should be enclosed by doublequotes**

To give an example if you want to load some entries with number and name to a table called `mytable` it should look like (tab instead of spaces):

```
mytable    number    codename
mytable    345       "Anna"
mytable    943       "Bob"
```

I am not sure about Microsoft Excel. You probably can save your sheet as a `Text(tab delimited)` after you add your first column for the table name and first row as the variable name. I use OpenOffice calc and to me the easiest way is to copy paste from calc to a text file.

[image: LibreOffice calc screenshot]

It is automatically tab separated then.

[image: Text editor screenshot]

The easiest way to understand what kind of format you need is to create the table of your desire in z-Tree then use table dumper. Then you can compare the format you have and the format you need.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for the answert - it definately helped a lot to understand the table loader function.

I get the idea of this function for tables with different variables. In my case, however, the table is a matrix. The idea is, that the payoff is generated using this table. This means, that the user chose a specific combination. Then ztree looks up this combination in the matrix table and reads out the predefined payoff.

Is there any difference or anything I have to consider when loading such a table into ztree?

Comment: Oh, I just saw this comment. Did you solve this issue? Maybe you can address your own question.