# Loading Parameter Table

Tags: ztree

I am trying to load a parameter table.

I get error messages when opening the Parameter Table and trying to load a txt file (created with Excel and saved as a tab-delimited txt) via `Treatmant -> Import Variable Table -> Group`.

I tried using the advice given here: [How to use table loader in ztree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54724211/how-to-use-table-loader-in-ztree)

But I cannot import the parameter table generated.

The error messages say, e.g.:

> Syntax error: line 1 (or above)
>
> Error in period 0; subject 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter table in z-Tree is a special table and (if I am not mistaken) they are not meant to be exported or imported.

I just assumed you would like to have a special matching structure. (If you are planing to do something else, my answer might not be relevant.)

If you want to manage the `Group` variable from a file, you can create a table, say `MATCHING` and load an external file the same way it is described in the post you put the link. For instance something like that:

```
Period    Subject    Group
1          1          3
1          2          3
1          3          2
...
2          1          2
2          2          1 
2          3          3
```

and you can add a program (subjects.do) as follows under the background stage:

```
Group = MATCHING.find(Subject == :Subject & Period == :Period, Group);
```

Just make sure you define the group for each subject and each period as if the program cannot find a valid entry for the subject and the period, it will create trouble.

Note: If you are using z-Tree 4, it seems that the variables need to be initiated first. This can be done by adding a program under the table. In z-Tree 3, this is not necessary.

[image: Loading an external matching file]

Comment: Thanks! I think your assumption is right. I tried to implement this, [see screenshot for the structure and the txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1t0kqtbvicvfrz2/Screenshot%202019-07-08%2018.46.55.png?dl=0). When I try to click "OK" I do, however, get the following:

`Syntax error: line 1 (or above)`

I also tried without the column "MATCHING" but get the same result.

Comment: Interesting. I will try to reproduce

Comment: I now managed to get around the syntax error with

`Group = MATCHING.find(same(Subject) & same(Period),Group);`

This should do the right thing, correct?

But now when I start the Treatment, I get the following error:

`Error(s) reading table "MATCHING": Variable(s) not defined: Subject, Group`

Comment: You are right, this is my mistake. Can you try to initialize those columns by adding a program that runs in MATCHING table as follows before you load your file:
`Subject = -1;` and `Group = -1;`

Comment: I am nearly there! [Here is my current setup](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wrznaoix1mfojhw/Screenshot%202019-07-17%2020.22.09.png?dl=0). 
I get the error: `Error(s) reading table "MATCHING": Variable(s) not defined: Group`. Am I doing something wrong with the Program? I tried `subjects.do` instead of `MATCHING.do` but then it claims that `Subject` is also not defined. I think I do not quite understand how initialising variables works. I also tried `Group = MATCHING.find(Subject == :Subject & Period == :Period, Group);` with the same result (error message).

Comment: Okay, guess we are done here @NCH32. [This functions for me.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fmgdda4qfojcdrb/2019-07-18%2021_40_52-zTree%20-%20matching.ztt.jpg?dl=0). I don't even need to initialize the variables. Note that I did not add the condition (Which filters your file and you should avoid).

Comment: Sadly this does not work for me, I get the same error again. It must be something about the txt file then. I've already re-created it a few times with different applications (Word, TextEdit, Excel). I have a Mac, maybe this is an issue. (If I remove the condition, I get the error in every period, otherwise just during the first.) I'll explore...

Comment: Can you try to TABLE DUMP the `subjects` table and modify that file accordingly. The usual suspect in the mac computers is the new line format. You can get to know more about it here: https://winsmarts.com/new-line-characters-in-text-files-between-mac-and-windows-3695b7beb685 

Unfortunately I don't have the files in my laptop and I am using Linux on this one. But on Monday I can post the text file that I used and you can try with that, unless you solve your problem until then.

Comment: Thanks! I tried three things: first, dumping the subjects table, then loading it. Here, I get the usual error `Variable(s) not defined: Subject, Group`. Second, I followed your link and tried all the commands there, which worked but the resulting txt files still throw the usual error. Third, I borrowed a windows laptop, created a table in Excel there, saved it as a tab-delimited txt, then transferred it to my Mac, started the Treatment and ran into the usual error. I did not manage to run my Treatment on the windows laptop because I cannot connect more than one zleaf.

Comment: Could you please tell me your z-Tree version? I will send you my file tomorrow so we can see if it functions.

Comment: On the Mac, I use 4.1.7, on Windows, I use 4.1.9

Comment: Okay, the problem was version specific. I was able to reproduce the error with version 4. Indeed the problem was the because the columns were not initiated. I updated the answer. Please see above. And here are the files that I used: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t6ngf1k0fanspra/matchingfromfile.rar?dl=0

Comment: THIS WORKS on my Mac! You are my hero and savior. :)

Comment: Oh I'm glad. Enjoyed every bit.